# CSS/JavaScript overflow Chrome bug?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm desperate.
Im trying to make custom form styling JS, it all works flawlessly, except I got this bug (only in Chrome).

https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9CIu.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9yZKA.png

When you click on the select twice, or you click on the list while its loading it jumps to left.

Only Chrome does this, other browsers seems to be OK.
Any ideas? Im trying to solve this for 3 hours with no success...

The problem doesnt occur when I put "overflow: hidden" on the DIV that contains the input... The list is positioned absolutely, so I dont understand why it interacts with surrounding elements...

Comment: Please create a self-contained http://jsfiddle.net/ demo and post your code here as well. If this other page is your demo site, and you fix it or remove it, the question becomes useless for future visitors. Screenshots could be useful too. Kind of related meta question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it.

Comment: Maybe fix the javascript error as well "if(x >= $(this).offset().left && x <= $(this).offset().left + $(this).outerWidth() &&" => "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'left' of null"

Comment: Felix: You're right, sorry. I was just afraid that I wont re-create the bug in the jsfiddle. It looks like the its just so stupid (my mistake) that Ill probably ask to delete the question >.<

Comment: Danack: Yes, I deleted most parts of the JS, so I probably deleted something too much :) I didnt have the error normally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Increase the table width to say 250px (limiting width is 199px). Its happening as table can't contain the select control at some point of time so it goes down. Select field collapses because table width is reduced by 2px for some reason (most probably CSS). Have some extra width to avoid that.

Comment: My goodess. Thank You. 
I just... just... my goodness. 3 hours. Table width. 
I should really take a rest...